# Create TensorFlow Dataset with custom file format

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, numpy, tensorflow

I am trying to create a tf.data.Dataset, where filenames are mapped to Depth images. My images are saved as raw binary, 320*240*4 bytes per file. Images are 320x240 pixels, with 4 bytes representing a pixel.

I cannot figure out how to create a parsing function that will take a tf.Tensor filename, and return a (240, 320) tf.Tensor containing my image.

Here is what I've tried.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import struct
import math
from os import listdir


class Dataset:
    def __init__(self):
        filenames = ["./depthframes/" + f for f in listdir("./depthframes/")]

        self._dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(filenames).map(Dataset._parse)

    @staticmethod
    def _parse(filename):
        img = DepthImage(filename)
        return img.frame


class DepthImage:
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.rows, self.cols = 240, 320
        self.f = open(path, 'rb')
        self.frame = []
        self.get_frame()

    def _get_frame(self):
        for row in range(self.rows):
            tmp_row = []
            for col in range(self.cols):
                tmp_row.append([struct.unpack('i', self.f.read(4))[0], ])
            tmp_row = [[0, ] if math.isnan(i[0]) else list(map(int, i)) for i in tmp_row]
            self.frame.append(tmp_row)

    def get_frame(self):
        self._get_frame()
        self.frame = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.array(self.frame).reshape(240, 320))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Dataset()
```

My error is as follows:

```
File "C:/Users/gcper/Code/STEM/msrdailyact3d.py", line 23, in __init__ 
    self.f = open(path, 'rb')
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not Tensor
```

Comment: You are using python operations on tf tensors. You have the [tf.py_func](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/py_func) method that can integrate python functions in to your tensorflow operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the suggestion of @kvsih, the following solution worked.

```
self._dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(filenames)\
    .map(lambda name: tf.py_func(self._parse, [name], tf.int32))
```

Also, `get_frame` cannot return a tensor. `self._parse` must return an `tf.int32`, as defined in the lambda above. The following code replaces `get_frame`

```
def get_frame(self):
    self._get_frame()
    self.frame = np.array(self.frame).reshape(240, 320)
```