# Tensorflow 2 creating custom dataset

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to build a custom dataset-loader, which laods [ICDAR](https://rrc.cvc.uab.es/?ch=4)-Dataset.
My frist step was to embed a dataset inside my loader as suggested also
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54373780/create-tensorflow-dataset-with-custom-file-format) in this post, but the problem is that you have to implement all the nice features that the tenfsoflow-2 class "Dataset" offers manually.

My second try was to subclass the Dataset-Class, something like:

```
class MyDataset(tf.data.Dataset):
  def __init__(self):
    super(MyDataset, self).init()

  def preprocess_images(self):
    pass
```

But the problem is i did not find any documentation what dataset-class internally really does, the only implementation i found was [this one](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py#L2349).

So question is does anybody know how to build a custom "dataset" in tf2 by subclassing tf.data.Dataset.

By the way i also tried tensorflow_datasets, bit it does not really worked, shince it will downlaod the dataset, and split them manually which is in this is alreay seperated by train and test and also ICDAr can not be downlaoded without registration.

**The content of the ICDAR-Dataset is as following:**

> An Image
>
> A List of all texts in each image
>
> A List of Bouding-boxes for each text in each image

**Image:** 
@https://rrc.cvc.uab.es/?ch=4 owns the copyrights of this image.
[image]

Words and bounding boxes for the above image:

```
377,117,463,117,465,130,378,130,Genaxis Theatre
493,115,519,115,519,131,493,131,[06]
374,155,409,155,409,170,374,170,###
492,151,551,151,551,170,492,170,62-03
376,198,422,198,422,212,376,212,Carpark
494,190,539,189,539,205,494,206,###
374,1,494,0,492,85,372,86,###
```

Thanks
does anyone know how to

Comment: It is a bit hard to help when we don't know the contents of the dataset. Can you provide a small example in terms of what are the inputs and what do you expect the output to be?

Comment: @gorjan plz check the updated question